# File not found error while uploading files

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I had a custom control in my web app that used for uploading multiple files.User first selects his files and then presses the upload button.When the file does not exist in user's system,The page can't load and the error file not found is displayed. How can I catch this error? because the user can upload more then one files, if a file doesn't exist,I want to display error message and process other files. It is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/files/")))
    {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/files/"));
    }

    HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
    {
        if (file.ContentLength <= 209715200)
        {
            var c = save.NameSave(file);
            fi.path = c;
            fi.title = file.FileName;
            userfiles.Add(fi);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be great if you provide your full code.

Comment: I loaded my web design. ![Valid XHTML] (http://i57.tinypic.com/2qsrmvk.png). by pressing "add more files" user can choose more than one file, by pressing "Process", processing files is started. when the file doesn't exist in local machine, when "Process" pressed,it displays "file not found".

Answer (score 0):

you can get and array of all files path that are selected by user then iterate some thing like this

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
 {
    if(!File.Exists(arr[i]))
      {
         //your file do not exist do what ever you want here;
      }
     else
      {
        //your file exists your code for remaining files that exists goes here!
      }
 }
```

Comment: when the file doesn't exist, the code isn't executed, I put break point in my code, but it isn't entered in code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the each files you have uploaded:
The below code checks whether the directory exists or not and provides file writing and reading permission.

```
foreach (string file in context.Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile hpf = context.Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFile;
                string rootPathForwritingfile=AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +"your destination folder name//"+Uri.UnescapeDataString(Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                //check for the directory exists or not
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(rootPathForwritingfile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                ReadWriteStream(hpf.InputStream, fileStream);

            }

private static void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
        {
            int Length = 256;
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
            int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
            // write the required bytes
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
            }
            readStream.Close();
            writeStream.Close();
        }
```

**

> Edited Answer for checking the file existence before upload using
>   Javascript:

**

```
$('#<%=btnUpload.ClientId%>').click(function(e){
  $.each($('#File1').files,function(index,file){
     if(type of file !== 'undefined' && file.size > 0)
      {
        alert('success');
        //do your stuff
      }
     else
      {
        alert('file not found');
        //do your stuff for breaking the event and warn the user that the file specified was not found.
        //try e.preventdefault();
      }
});
});
```

Comment: My problem is when the file doesn't exist in local machine, the page doesn't execute any code. I used breakpoints and when the page was loading,it didn't go to code behind.

Comment: @mansureh Can you post your HTML code which has been used for uploading files.